My ubuntu autoinstall yaml file password isn't working
I've followed this instruction to generate an encrypted password for my autoinstall .yaml file replacing the 'FhcddHFVZ7ABA4Gi' with my password and enclosing it with single quotes but the system doesn't recognize my password after install, what do I do? What's the correct command to generate my password?
I've tried with
$ openssl passwd

but I don't think this will works as well since the return is too small

You need to run printf 'root' | openssl passwd -6 -salt 'FhcddHFVZ7ABA4Gi' -stdin changing root to your desired password, then copy-paste the output of the command (the long string / salted and hashed password) in the YAML file as the password value. I closed this as a duplicate of the question you linked as this appears to be just a misunderstanding of the instruction provided in the answer. If it's not please explain why, ping me with @kos and I'll reopen it
